# WIndows 10 can't boot from GRUB2 but can boot from WIndows Bootload Manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 to MSI GL63-8RC laptop which had Windows 10 initially. I made GRUB2 the default bootloader and it could boot Ubuntu without problems. Then I tried to boot Windows 10 from GRUB2 from the option

> Windows Boot Manager (/dev/sda1))
>
> Which should be the correct place according to sudo fdisk -l output.

but received a blue screen which says

> winload.efi is corrupted or missing.

If I spam F11 while laptop is loading and enter boot options, I can select Windows Boot Manager and it boots without problems. I looked into other askubuntu threads which suggested stuff like disabling secure boot, disabling hibernation etc. but none of them solved the problem. Any ideas to why GRUB can't boot into Windows 10?

(If that matters, Windows installation is in my internal SSD while Ubuntu installation is in an external SSD.)

Comment: Yes, make sure Fast Startup is disabled in Windows. Then boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`..

Comment: If external drive, you really want grub installed to external drive and grub install defaults to internal drive. Others with MSI systems have also needed UEFI updates. Both systems need to be in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sXncgXgyV8/

Comment: Interesting that you have an ESP on sdc, but of course Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer installed Ubuntu's UEFI boot files to ESP on sda. And UEFI shows Windows boot entries from both ESPs. Edit fstab, and change its mount of efi partition from sda1's UUID to sdc2's ESP. Then reinstall grub so it uses sdc2 for ESP. Then in UEFI make sure Windows from sda is second in boot order & grub is first. Windows will not work from external/USB drive.

Comment: @oldfred I am having a bit of a rough time here sorry for the inconvenience. I was trying to figure out how to do what you said and even saw this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 thread where you commented. I used blkid to see my external SSD's UUID but I have no idea how should I edit the fstab and reinstalling grub seems like a task where I have to deal with iso's and stuff again if I am not missing something.  I have been using Linux for like 5 days so sorry if I am clueless

Comment: I was going to post details on copying UUID from sdc2 into fstab. But then noticed it was the same UUID. You copied partitions from internal drive to external drive. You can then only boot when external drive is disconnected as duplicate UUIDs are not allowed. `sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdaX` see also `man tune2fs` as I never have had to change an UUID. You need to change the duplicates which look like sdc2 & sdc1. You also have duplicate GUID on sdc3 & sdc4. Since you cannot boot Windows from external drive I might just delete sdc3 as it is just unformatted space required by Windows.

Comment: @oldfred I receive this error > tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1 contains a ntfs file system  < I looked at it and it seems like that command can't edit windows UUIDs. I went to WIndows DIsk Management to unmount and mount the volume since I read it changes the UUID but that also didn't help.

Comment: You can use gdisk to edit all the UUID & GUIDs. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462260&page=3&p=14039563#post14039563 But have to reinstall grub, edit fstab & maybe some other places that use UUID. UEFI boots from GUID aka partUUID.  to see UUID & partUUIDs. `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`

Comment: @oldfred I followed the steps and  now sdc3 & sdc4 all have different partUUIDs but sdc1 & sdc2 still have duplicate UUIDs. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XHCTVmd85X/

Comment: Do not know about Windows. But sda1 & sdc2 and sda4 & sdc1 are duplicates. You need to change one or the other. And I would make sure I have good backup of Windows. Only change the one you do not now use which should be the copy on external drive.

Comment: OK, I think I finally did it https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yFqPmVpRnb/. You said you were going to post details on copying UUID to fstab before this duplicate UUID problem, is it OK now?

Comment: @oldfred oops, I forgot to tag you sorry

Comment: Your sda1 & sdb2 are both `EA41-1959 `.

Comment: @oldfred sdb2 is EA42-1969, but I should probably change it to something more random

Comment: This duplicate UUID issue and the time it takes to resolve it, it one of the main reasons to do a new install. Major houseclean is another reason and verification of restore procedure from backup is a third. Once I have a drive partitioned & installer booted into RAM, I can install to SSD in about 10 minutes. Re-installing apps is slowest part of process and rsync restore of data if relatively quick.

Comment: @oldfred I did the reinstallation by following this link from the bug's thread https://askubuntu.com/a/1056079/152287 just to be safe and it worked. Thank you so much